# jQuery, next, prev, cycling to first and last

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for this confusing title.
What i'm trying to do is a function (or just a simple way), which will do simple **.next()**, but if there's no next element, match first. And the same for **.prev()** - if there's no previous element, match last.
So i made it this way:

```
var current_selected = getSelected();
if(current_selected.length) {
    var prev = current_selected.prev();
    if(prev.length) {
        setSelected(prev);
        return;
    }
}
setSelected(getLast());
```

But i don't really like it, i think there's some pretty way do it. Any thoughts?
(**getSelected** and **getLast** returns jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for `prev` case

```
var current_selected = getSelected();

var prev = current_selected.prev();
if(prev.length) {
    setSelected(prev);
} else {
    setSelected(getLast());
}
```

Comment: I've selected this, because i need this functionality only once. If someone needs this more often, the next answer is better.

Answer (score 6):

You could create some little convenience plugins:

```
$.fn.nextWrap = function() {
    var $next = this.next();
    if ($next.length) return $next;
    return this.siblings().first();
};

$.fn.prevWrap = function() {
    var $prev = this.prev();
    if ($prev.length) return $prev;
    return this.siblings().last();
};
```

Then you can simply do `$('#something').nextWrap()` or `$('#something').prevWrap()`.

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qpDKL/

**Note:** This will behave mostly like `prev()` and `next()` (with the wrap behavior, of course), but it doesn't support the `prev|next(selector)` syntax.

---

Edit: Here's a slightly more terse plugin syntax since they're nearly the same anyway:

```
$.each(['next', 'prev'], function(i, nextOrPrev) {
    $.fn[nextOrPrev + 'Wrap'] = function() {
        var $item = this[nextOrPrev]();
        if ($item.length) return $item;
        return this.siblings()[nextOrPrev === 'next' ? 'first' : 'last']();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I can think of would be to have an array of the elements that you want to cycle.  You can cycle through an array in two ways:

```
array.push(array.shift());
```

or

```
var count = 0;
function cycle() {
    return array[count++ % array.length];
}
```

I think the former looks cleaner.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/feeF5/

Answer (score 0):

Something around these lines:

```
if (!$('selected').next().length)
    return $('selected').parent().children().first();
else
    return $('selected').next();

if (!$('selected').prev().length)
    return $('selected').parent().children().last();
else
    return $('selected').prev();
```